# Changing size of numbers on axes in CorePlot

Tags: swift, graph, core-plot

How to change size of numbers on axes? I need to embed 100 numbers on y axis but for now it looks awful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the text size with a text style. Set the `labelTextStyle` on the axis for the major tick labels and/or the `minorTickLabelTextStyle` for the minor tick labels.

Example code to set up a text style:

```
CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
textStyle.color    = [CPTColor grayColor];
textStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
textStyle.fontSize = 18.0;
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how can I implement this. Can you write code for this? Please

Comment: Still don't understand how to make it work. Don't know how to reach text style of labels on the axes

Comment: When setting up the axis properties, `axis.labelTextStyle = textStyle;`. There are other style properties available, too. See the [`CPTTextStyle` docs](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_text_style.html) for details.

Comment: Finally, I did this. Thanks, Eric. But I've got another question - I have double values on the axes (0.0 , 1.0 , 2.0 , etc), how can I make it integer? (just 0, 2 , 3)

Comment: Use the [`labelFormatter`](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_axis.html#ace21201606fe09e4209aa85539995d02) to change the number format for the axis labels.

Comment: There are several examples in the *Plot Gallery* example app and some of the others, as well.

Comment: Eric, please, I need your help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49743016/swift-4-coreplot-send-chart-via-mail-app-with-messageui