# Swift 4, CorePlot, send chart via mail app (with MessageUI)

Tags: swift, email, graph, charts, core-plot

Can I somehow take the chart (which was made with CorePlot) from view and send it as a file to another person via mail app? I want to send mail with the help of MessageUI. I feel fine if just the picture will be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-imageOfLayer` method to get a PNG of the graph or the `-dataForPDFRepresentationOfLayer` method to get a PDF and attach the resulting file to a message.

Comment: Excuse me, I have another problem with understanding. When I get this image, it has a particular size, and the numbers are overlapping each other. What I did in my app is just change orientation to landscape. But I didn't succeeded getting image of the right size (where numbers don't overlap). Can I change it somehow? (If it matters, I have a line graph)

Comment: The Core Plot graph doesn’t have to be on screen at all. Set the size of the graph layer to whatever you want before exporting the image.

Comment: I tried different things, but I can't do it. Can you write an example, please?

Comment: Create a graph and set it up normally, but don’t add it to a hosting view. The `size` of the graph’s `frame` rectangle determines the dimensions of the exported image.

Comment: I wrote this: 
graph?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 500).
Though I still get "Height and width -  Optional(500.0) Optional(320.0)" when this code is called: 
print("Height and width  - ", self.viewContainsGraphs.hostedGraph?.imageOfLayer()?.size.height, self.viewContainsGraphs.hostedGraph?.imageOfLayer()?.size.width)

Comment: my graph is CPTXYGraph

Comment: The graph will always be the same size as its hosting view (`viewContainsGraphs`). Don’t add the graph to a hosting view if you want a different size.

Comment: I just changed the size of hosting view and made it to vary for traits. Thanks a lot